# Generate HMACSHA1 in ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, hmacsha1

I have the following code snippet to generate an HMACSHA1 signature in C#. Which is the following code

```
Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
HMACSHA1 hmac = new HMACSHA1(encoding.GetBytes(SecretKey.ToCharArray()));

StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();

data.Append(Access);
data.Append(Id);
data.Append(Entity);
data.Append(Username);

string signature Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(encoding.GetBytes(data.ToString().ToCharArray())));
```

Now I want to translate that to ruby, something like:

```
Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), secret_key, data)
```

However, the result is not the equal for the same input. Do they use different hashing algorithms internally?

Thanks

Comment: HMAC SHA1 when fed the same bytes for message and secret should always produce the same hash. Different languages and libraries *should* implement the exact same algorithm. What is the character encoding of the key and data you have in the Ruby version (use e.g. `puts secret_key.encoding` to check)? Also at a guess you are encoding the `hexdigest` in Ruby, but calling `ComputeHash` in C# - if the latter outputs raw bytes then the two calls are not equivalent.

Comment: Correct, that was the issue. On ruby I used hexdigest which was not what C# was using exactly

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the responses the problem had to do with encoding and not using raw bytes when generated the HMAC SHA1 hash

Comment: If you have time, this answer would be better if it showed, using a couple of lines of code, how you could tell what was wrong (without the encoding data - controlled by code you didn't show - no-one could answer the question), and also very importantly what the correct line of Ruby code was.